# Выбор региона сайта посредством php, cookie и jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookie, php, wordpress

Помогите новичку. Требуется реализовать на сайте выбор региона. Т.е, юзер кликает на ссылку, вылазит модальное окно и выполняется выбор региона. Также после того, как пользователь выберит регион он должен сохранится посредством cookie и главная страница должна изменить адрес на вид: [mypage.ru/region/.](http://mypage.ru/region/.) И должна быть такой все время существования кука.

Настроил запомнинание региона, но не знаю, как реализовать изменение адреса главной страницы. Подскажите, как реализовать. Движок WordPress.

Comment: > не знаю как реализовать изменение адреса главной страницы
Это и есть вопрос?
    header("Location: /region");

Comment: Да это и был вопрос. Но ответа не понял)

Comment: Движок WordPress. А самописный слабо сделать?

Comment: А собственно к чему клоните? Да слабо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так понятней? :D Не вижу проблемы.

```
<?php
header("Location: /region");
?>
```

Comment: Допер. Спасибо большое.